# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The maximum length of cell contents (text) is 32767 characters

Tags: java

заполняю Excel файл, не хватает размера ячейки, вот такой формат данных:

```java
{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[63.291653,61.309102], [63.29164,61.309089]...]}
```

Предлагали записывать вместо xls в xlsx типо размер увеличен в 2 раза. Попытался, не прокатило, просто менял формат файла.

```java
if (coordinates.length() > 32767){
   coordinatesDuble.append(Integer.toString(coordinates.length() / 2));
}
```

Пытался так поделить строку и записать в следующую ячейку, все равно исключение:

```java
// coordinate
cell = row.createCell(8, CellType.NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(coordinates.toString());
// coordinatesDuble
cell = row.createCell(9, CellType.NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(coordinatesDuble.toString());
```

Подскажите решение пожалуйста

Весь код:

```java
for (HashMap<String, String> str : strings) {

    rownum++;
    row = sheet.createRow(rownum);

    List<HashMap<String, String>> points = hm.get(str.hashCode());

    String tempStart = "{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[";
    StringBuilder coordinates = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder coordinatesDuble = new StringBuilder();
    coordinates.append(tempStart);

    for (HashMap<String, String> point : points) {
        coordinates.append("[" + point.get("longitude") + "," + point.get("latitude") + "], ");
    }
    String tempEnd = "]}";
    coordinates.append(tempEnd);

    if (coordinates.length() > 32767){
        coordinatesDuble.append(Integer.toString(coordinates.length() / 2));
    }

    // coordinate
    cell = row.createCell(8, CellType.NUMERIC);
    cell.setCellValue(coordinates.toString());
    // coordinatesDuble
    cell = row.createCell(9, CellType.NUMERIC);
    cell.setCellValue(coordinatesDuble.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть дело в том, что в `cellType.NUMERIC` пытаешься записать строку? Попробуй поменять тип ячейки.

Comment: ```java // coordinate
            cell = row.createCell(8, CellType.STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(coordinates.toString()); ```
Та же самая ошибка, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The maximum length of cell contents (text) is 32767 characters

Answer (score 0):

Total number of characters that a cell can contain - 32,767 characters
[Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)